# how to cause word wrap when slotted content added to flexbox;

Tags: css, flexbox

I have some markup in a custom element like so

```html
<div class="competition">
  <slot><slot>
  <div id="compname">2019 Football Competition</div>
</div>
```

When there is no slotted content I would like this panel to look like this (ascii art)

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|                    2019 Football Competition                       |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

that is centered on a single line.  I would like it to remain like that if the slotted content
is not very much , so for instance if the slotted content was set up like this

```html
<my-competition-header>
  <div>Joe Bloggs</div>
  <div>2:14:16</div>
</my-competition-header>
```

I end of with something like this

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|   Joe Bloggs       2:14:16           2019 Football Competition    |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

That is nicely spread out with space around.

Bit if the content was a bit longer such that it didn't all fit or the device displaying it was smaller
I would like to end up with this

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|                                                          2019     |
|   JoeBloggsHasVeryLongNameSUCHTHATITOVERFLOWS 2:14:16  Football   |
|                                                       Competition |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I've tried various forms of css like this (this solves my first and second issues, but falls apart on the last one).

```css
  .competition
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-around;  
    align-items: center;     
  }
  ::slotted(*) {
    flex: 1 0 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
  } 
  .competition>div#compname {
    flex: 0 1 auto;
    margin: 0;
  }
```

On the last one it ends up like this

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|                                                  2019             |
|JoeBloggsHasVeryLongNameSUCHTHATITOVERFLOWS2:14:16Football         |
|                                                  Competition      |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

and I dont quite understand why.  Can anyone suggest how I can solve this

Comment: can you add `text-align:center;` on `#compname`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use multi columns layout by using `column-count` and `colmn-width` like

```
div {
 -webkit-column-count: 3;
 -moz-column-count: 3;
 column-count: 3;
}
```

```
div {
 -webkit-column-width: 150px;
 -moz-column-width: 150px;
 column-width: 150px;
}
```

or you can simply use the grid box to prevent your page from keeping you stressing about that

```css
.competition {
  display: grid;
  width: 100%;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

div {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="competition">
  <div>Joe Bloggs | Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis
    aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
  <div>2:14:16| Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
    irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
  <div id="compname">2019 Football Competition | Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think he wants something more dynamic

Comment: this is not what I am after.  The "compname" div is always going to be in the right third of the competition div in your solution, whereas I need it to spread out over the entire width when there is no slotted content